# Change $scope variable based on screen size

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, responsive-design

I have a sidebar which I collapse based on a value in `$scope` (let's say `$scope.open` for easy understanding). At the moment, when you click on the close/open button it just toggles that value, but if the menu is open it's going to look really ugly on mobile devices or small windows. So, I want to close the menu (set `$scope.open` to `false`) if the user is on a mobile sized device or using a small screen. Normally in CSS I would just use `@media...` and create a media query to add some styles on mobile devices, but in this case I want to do something similar but with a `$scope` variable.

Basically I want to do the equivalent of a media query but with my `$scope.open` variable to make sure the menu minimizes when on mobile. Any ideas?

Comment: using the $window service you could set up a resize event handler - if the size is below your breakpoint, set the scope variable?

Comment: @Starscream1984 I will take a look, I wasn't sure how to do that within angular so was seeing what I could find here

Comment: Are you using bootstrap in for styling?

Comment: @VVK Im using bootstrap yep, and ui.bootstrap too on the angular side of things

Comment: can you post your code please.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary, it's just a simple toggle. Something like `ng-class="{'closed': !open}"` on the sidebar element and in `.closed` I set the css styles for the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can do something like

```
$scope.open = $(document).height() > 500; // can be different
```

Comment: it needs to be in a directive .. that's the angular way

Answer (score 0):

May be a good idea create a directive to access dom using jQuery:

```
.directive('onloadDirective', function(){
return {
   restrict: 'A',
   scope: {
      open: '='
   }
   link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
       $(window).load(function() {
           //get element
           var myElement = $("#myElement");
           if (myElement.width() > 100 && myElement.height() < 200) {
               scope.open = true;
           } else {
               scope.open = false;
           }
       });
   }
```

}
});

Solution with vanilla js and angular

```
    .directive('onloadDirective', function(){
return {
   restrict: 'A',
   scope: {
      open: '='
   }
   link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
       window.onload = function() {
           //get width
           var w = window.innerWidth;
           if (w > 100 && w < 200) {
               scope.open = true;
           } else {
               scope.open = false;
           }
       });
   }
```

}
});

and your HTML can be like this:

```
<body ng-controller="myController" onload-directive open="open">
</body>
```

Comment: I like the logic of the directive, but I'd reaaally want to use native JS or a pure angular solution. I really don't want to use jQuery to solve this just because it's easier :P

Comment: haha no problem. We can remove jquery and use vanillajs on the directive. 1 min.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, Then the right way would be to add `hidden-xs` and `hidden-sm` class to your sidebar div.

This will hide the sidebar on mobile devices, While it will still be visible on all the devices having screen resolution `≥992px`. So it doesn't look bad on them.

Comment: I don't want to hide it. When I set `$scope.open` to `false`, it basically changes the width of the sidebar and the main section, which shrinks the sidebar but doesn't hide it.

Comment: Why do you want to shrink it instead of hiding. Whats the advantage.

Comment: It's not your typical sidebar, the purpose isn't that important really :P

Comment: bootstrap doesn't help for all resolutions. Sometimes you need to put some custom css class

Comment: I guess he knows about this and the OP is about angular not BS>

Answer (score 0):

Building on Luiz's answer, you can create a directive

```
.directive('onloadDirective', function($window){
return {
   restrict: 'A',
   scope: {
      open: '='
   }
   link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      if ($window.innerWidth < 200) {
          scope.open = true;
      }
   }
  }  
});
```

Add the directive to the body tag or your `ui-view`, bind to your scope variable (don't put primitive values on the scope - [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) )